# Fail to download caffe model

Tags: caffe

I tried the following command to download bvlc_alexnet model.

python scripts/download_model_binary.py models/bvlc_alexnet

But, it failed, displaying error message:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out

The following url is also not working.
http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Since this is a transient problem, I recommend deleting this question.  I'm glad you got an answer, but I think that keeping the question active is not likely enough to be of benefit to future searchers.

Comment: I don't know why the caffe server didn't respond. Also don't konw why this strange problem disappeared mysteriously. If caffe site not work  again, this thread could be a kind of help, like 'if caffe site not working, try next morning and everything goes ok'.

Comment: That advice is a general "reboot / wait" tactic for any internet connection.  It's not specific enough to leave on this site ... in my opinion.  I registered my vote to close; if we don't get 4 more to support my opinion, there's my answer.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue with your connection (which is odd since you posed the question). It could be a DNS issue which would explain why I can download the model you linked above and you can't.

Try using the IP: 169.229.222.251 Which is what dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org resolves to. You can also change the domain to the IP in the models/bvlc_alexnet/readme.md file to try the script again.

I checked the domain here and it looks like there's an issue (at the time of this post): http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org

Comment: Thank you. This moring I tried again and it worked.When I post the question, caffe site didn't work, probably down. I googled around and found nothing and end up here. Nobody cares? I doubt.